# Can I use javascript to display a message once email is sent?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use jquery to display a message to the user once the php has checked if the users submission was sent? For example if the user has entered their name, email and message. They click the submit button and the message has been sent, could I then somehow run some javascript that would fade in a message saying "message sent".

```js
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Al-Saba.net'; 
    $to = 'lukie@al-saba.net'; 
    $subject = 'Email Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

```css
  body {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
     color: #ccc;
     z-index: -100;
     background-color: black;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
}
 .title {
     margin-top: 20%;
     color: #56ffc6;
     font-size: 3.6em;
     opacity: .9;
     cursor: default;
     text-align: left;
}
/* Labels are titles for the text fields. You can use a placeholder instead if you like*/
 label {
     display:block;
     margin-top:20px;
     letter-spacing:2px;
}
/* Centres the form within the page */
 form {
     margin:0 auto;
     width:459px;
}
/* Styles the text boxes */
 input, textarea, file {
     width:439px;
     height:27px;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .14);
     border-radius:5px;
     -moz-border-radius:5px;
     -webkit-border-radius:5px;
     border:1px solid #dedede;
     padding:10px;
     margin-top:3px;
     font-size:0.9em;
     color:#d6d6d6;
     transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
 :focus {
     outline: none !important;
     border:1px solid #36d1ed;
}
/* Styles the text area boxes (message field) */
 textarea {
     height:213px;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .14);
}
/* Styles the submit button */
 #submit {
     color: whitesmoke;
     background-color: #5f5f5f;
     width: 250px;
     height:48px;
     text-align: center;
     border:none;
     margin-top:20px;
     cursor:pointer;
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
/* Styles the submit hover */
 #submit:hover {
     background-color: #7fd8ff;
     transform: scale(1.1);
}
 @keyframes rotate-one {
     0% {
         transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
     100% {
         transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-two {
     0% {
         transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
     100% {
         transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-three {
     0% {
         transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
     100% {
         transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            <div class="noselect title">Contact</div>
                                            <label></label>
                                            <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
                                                <label></label>
                                                <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">
                                                    <label></label>
                                                    <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                                    </form>
```

Comment: Yeah lookup submit function for jquery forms

Comment: Well, sure, you can do lots of things with JavaScript.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  There's no JavaScript here, and your page already displays success/failure messages to the user based on the result of the `mail()` function.

Comment: Certainly. You submit the form as AJAX request to the server, the server replies _after_ having sent out the message. You can interpret the positive or negative response you receive for your AJAX request on the client side and visualize whatever you want.

Comment: There are multiple ways, best would be to handle the submission asynchronously then based on the response from PHP display the `success` or `error` message, or else you would need to redirect/reload the page and using parse the GET headers for `success` or `error`.

Comment: I would like to just have some big text to fade onto the screen for maybe 2 seconds and show the success or error message then fade out. I don't want it to go to a knew page. I'm not sure how to let the javascript know if the email was sent successfully or not.

Comment: I have used a tiny out the box script that you can easily find (sweet alert) and that will match your needs : need to use what was suggested above : ajax / response from php then SA -> GIYSBF :)

Comment: Use ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and use the `success` callback to display the message, and alternatively the `error` callback to show any errors.

Comment: @OpticLukie: What you're essentially looking for is a tutorial and examples of AJAX with PHP.  There are many to be found on Google.  Most of the code you posted in the question isn't really related to that.  And the "email" portion of it isn't entirely relevant either.  Your server-side code would send whatever data you like to your client-side code in response to the AJAX request.  The fact that the data is a success/fail notice for an email isn't really important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **YES**. You will need to create an AJAX (asynchronous) request to your PHP script which will preform the `mail()` function, based-on the email going through or not return a boolean `TRUE|FALSE` back to javascript, which based on that boolean that PHP is responding back display a `error` or `success` message.

**Reference:**

- [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp)
- [Walkthrough Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

**Example:**

I went ahead and created you a mock example of how it will look with comments explain step-by-step on how to make a AJAX `request` and how to handle the `response` when it comes back from PHP, and the logic to display either a `success` or `error` message on the interface.

```
init=()=>{
    //CREATE NEW AJAX REQUEST
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //SET LISTENER TO HANDLE RESPONSE FROM SERVER (PHP)
    request.onreadystatechange = function()=>{
        //IF THE STATE OF THE REQUEST CHANGES TO (4) RESPONSE HAS CAME BACK FROM SERVER
        if(this.readyState == 4){
            //SERVER(PHP) RETURNS TRUE|FALSE IF MAIL() FUNCTION EXECUTED
            //THIS IS SHORTHAND (IF STATEMENT) SO IF TRUE|FALSE SET (messageText)
            var messageText = (this.responseText) ? 'whatever success message you want' : 'whatever error message you want';
            //CREATE MESSAGE BOX
            var message = document.createElement('message');
            //INSERT (messageText) INTO (messageBox)
            message.innerHTML = messageText;
            //APPEND TO INTERFACE
            document.body.appendChild(message);
        }
    }
    //CONFIGURE REQUEST WITH (METHOD,URL)
    request.open("POST","/path/to/your/php/script");
    //SEND REQUEST TO PHP 
    request.send();
}
//ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

Comment: So if I created a javascript file with this in it and linked it to my html file would it work?

Comment: Yeah you would just have to change out the `path/to/your/php/script` and then obviously add styling to the `<message>` tag that contains the display message.

Comment: So how would I apply styling to the message tag? Is that a class in css or something else? Sorry Im really new to this...

Comment: same way you would apply styling with any other html element, and you don't have to use `<message>` I just used a more semantic tag rather then a `<div>`. so in your css file it would just be `message{ //STYLES HERE}`

Comment: also don't get confused with this AJAX stuff, all it means is it's an OUT OF SYNC request, so when a page loads it's synchronous meaning everything loads all at once together, where as this is making a request "out of sync" from when the initial page load takes place.

Comment: whenever I submit a email it takes me to a blank page that says "Thank you for your email!" at the top left. Not sure what is wrong, I did everything that you told me to do. Seems like its using the message from php.

Comment: @OpticLukie If the page is redirecting that means it's reloading... aka not ASYNC, so if your using `<form>` tag and `<button type="submit">` browsers interpret that and reload the page as a default behavior, what you'll have to do is either `preventDefault` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault on the form or just use `<button type="button">` so the browser won't apply the default behavior to reload the page.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#submit').on('submit',function(){
    //Code goes here
   //maybae fade div in thats hidden that says message sent
   //make setTimout function to hide message after x seconds
   //or make an x button that hides the div

});
```